# How to write a dictionary of lists with different length to csv?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write this following python dictionary of lists with different length to csv.

```
dic = {'a': ['ACI', 'BBY', 'AMRX'], 'b': ['ABM', 'AG']}
```

The expected output is:

[image: expected out put]

Comment: You are doing nothing but iterating over the values of the dictionary.

Comment: So what is the input ? That is unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'a': ['ACI', 'BBY', 'AMRX'], 'b': ['ABM', 'AG']} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index') #Convert dict to df
print(df)
df.to_csv("final.csv",header=False) #Convert df to csv
```

Comment: Do you know how to read this csv to have the same dictionary from csv?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `csv` module:

```
# convert your dict to a list
lst = [[k] + v for k, v in dic.items()]

# write all rows at once
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

```
>>> %cat 'test.csv'
a,ACI,BBY,AMRX
b,ABM,AG
```

Comment: thank you so much! such an easy fix but works perfectly!
Could you also tell me, how one can change it such that the keys are the columns and the values are rows?

Answer (score 1):

just loop over the values of the dict and write them to a file.
No external library is required.

```
dic = {'a': ['ACI', 'BBY', 'AMRX'], 'b': ['ABM', 'AG']}
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key, values in dic.items():
        f.write(key + ',' + ','.join(values) + '\n')
```

out.csv

```
a,ACI,BBY,AMRX
b,ABM,AG
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "equal length" requirement in python's vanilla [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.  Simply iterating over the dictionary and outputting the rows should do the trick

```py
import csv

dic = {'a': ['ACI', 'BBY', 'AMRX'], 'b': ['ABM', 'AG']}
with open('/path/to/output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # python `dicts` are unordered, but assuming you 
    # want the rows in key-alphabetical order 
    for key, vals in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda k: k[0]):
        writer.writerow([key] + vals)
```

If however, you want to ensure lines are of equal length, you can first run a pass to figure out the max length:

```
max_len = max(len(val) for val in dic.values())
```

then fill accordingly when writing out each row

```
writer.writerow([key] + vals + [None] * (max_len - len(vals)))
```